# collapse spread not disappear after dialog hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I made a modal dialog with css:visibility hidden and visible.

```
<div id="myModal">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href = "#spread">
    <span class = "caret"></span>Spread
  </a>
  <div id = "spread" class = "panel-collapse collapse">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick = "HideModal()">Hide Modal</button>
```

Javascript code

```
HideModal(){
var modal = document.GetElementById("myModal");
modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

All things working well but menu with collapse is not working well.
If I open the menu and hide the dialog all things disappear but spread is not disappear.
Is there anyone who have met this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line

```
modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

In my experiment with your question, visibility collapse will override visibility hidden.

**Solution**
Change *HideModal()* content to

```
$('#myModal').addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to what I guess, in my case hidden class is not appropriate, any way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the collapse class to the div you wish to collapse.

```
<div id="myModal">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href = "#spread" style="display:block">
    <span class = "caret"></span>Spread
  </a>
  <div class="collapse"  id="spread">
   ...
  </div>
  <button>Hide Modal</button>
</div>
```

```css
a{display:block}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <div id="myModal">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href = "#spread">
        <span class = "caret"></span>Spread
      </a>
      <div class="collapse"  id="spread">
       ...
      </div>
      <button>Hide Modal</button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just tested this code out in one of the pages I have open - clicking the link toggles the collapse on the div #spread as expected - the causes a layout issue with the hide modal button moving up to beside the link text - but thats due to the inline dispaly of the link. So the toggle on the button works as expected.

Comment: Are you adding Bootstrap and jquery to your page as required?

Comment: I just added a code snippet to show the spred div toggling collapse on the click of the link - works fine - by clicking the "Spread" link - the div toggles the collapse class - is this not what you want?